# Logging in on mod_conversejs served page returns errors

Tags: ejabberd

Installed version: ejabberd-23.10

Installed on OS: Ubuntu 20.04 via apt-get

Config changes:

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /websocket: ejabberd_http_ws
      /conversejs: mod_conversejs
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
      /websocket: ejabberd_http_ws
      /conversejs: mod_conversejs

modules:
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_conversejs: 
    websocket_url: "ws://@HOST@:5280/websocket"
```

[image: Chrome error]

[image: Firefox error]

I have ejabberd installed on xinghaizhandui.com, messaging is fine with Windows and Android clients. Now I am trying to enable the conversejs web client, http://xinghaizhandui.com:5280/conversejs. The logging page shows up fine, but when I log in, the following errors show up, what does I have to do?

I am using this guide.
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-conversejs

Top：error in Chrome, Edge. Bottom: error in Firefox.

Comment: You should update your post explaining what ejabberd version number you are using, how you installed it, and what configuration changes did you do to the  default configuration. Also what Conversejs version you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Badlop, I have updated the post with the details

Answer (score 0):

That configuration should work

> Now I am trying to enable the conversejs web client, http://xinghaizhandui.com:5280/conversejs

In ejabberd.yml do you have something like this?

```yaml
hosts:
  - xinghaizhandui.com
```

And the account you try to login to is inside that host (for example eddy@xinghaizhandui.com ) ?

In ejabberd 23.10 that configuration should work both with Firefox and with Chrome (I have tested now with Firefox 115.6 and Chrome  120.0.6099.199)

Just for testing, you can remove some options in 5443, keep them in 5280 only, and let the mod_conversejs detect the options itself:

```yaml
listen:
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /websocket: ejabberd_http_ws
      /conversejs: mod_conversejs

modules:
  # disabled mod_bosh, not needed # mod_bosh: {}
  mod_conversejs: {}
```

If login works correctly with that configuration, you can start playing to improve the encryption, for example

```yaml
listen:
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /websocket: ejabberd_http_ws
      /conversejs: mod_conversejs

modules:
  # disabled mod_bosh, not needed # mod_bosh: {}
  mod_conversejs: {}
```

With that configuration, the website would be https://xinghaizhandui.com:5443/conversejs